# How the elements are storing?

Tags: c

I have written simple C code to find structure size and I don't how the memory is allocated.

```
struct s {
    long e;
    char c;
    float f;
    char d;
};

int main() {
    struct s a;
    printf("%d", sizeof(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `24`

Kindly explain me, How the output came? your help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: OT: `printf("%d", sizeof(a));` --> `printf("%zu", sizeof(a));`

Comment: The topic you are looking for is packing/padding/alignment, example discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing (there are lots more if you search the keywords)

Comment: You can also explore the details using `offsetof` as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56877779/21105992

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code might actually have undefined behavior as you pass a value of type `size_t` where `printf` expects an `int` for `%d`.  If `int` and `size_t` have a different representation, as is the case on most 64-bit systems, the code has undefined behavior and the output might be totally meaningless. You should use `%zu` or cast the argument as `(int)sizeof(a)`.

In your case, the systems reports a structure size of 24 bytes, which is more than the combined sizes of the members because of padding. The C compiler inserts padding bytes between some of the members and possibly at the end of the structure to ensure that each member is stored at a memory address corresponding to its alignment requirements.

Here is how it works:

- `long e;` is 8 bytes and requires 8 byte alignment. offset is 0
- `char c;` is 1 byte, no alignment,  offset is 8
- `float f;` is 4 bytes and 4 byte alignment, therefore 3 padding bytes are inserted between `c` and `f`,  offset is 12
- `char d;` is 1 byte, no alignment, offset is 16
- 7 padding bytes are inserted at the end of the structure to make its length a multiple of the largest alignment, hence 8 bytes.

The total size of the structure is 24 bytes, as reported.

You could reduce the overhead size by changing the order of fields, moving `d` before `f` or `f` before `c`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s1 {
    long e;   // offset  0, size 8, bytes [0..7]
    char c;   // offset  8, size 1, byte  [8]
              // 3 padding bytes          [9..11]
    float f;  // offset 12, size 4, bytes [12..15]
    char d;   // offset 16, size 1, byte  [16]
              // 7 padding bytes          [17..23]
};

struct s2 {
    long e;   // offset  0, size 8, bytes [0..7]
    float f;  // offset  8, size 4, bytes [8..11]
    char c;   // offset 12, size 1, byte  [12]
    char d;   // offset 13, size 1, byte  [13]
              // 2 padding bytes          [14..15]
};

int main(void) {
    struct s1 a;
    struct s2 b;
    printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(b)); // prints 24 16
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that the size and alignment requirements for standard types `short`, `int`, `long`, `float` and `double` vary from one architecture to another.  Your program and the one above would produce different output on Windows systems.